# Does PHP parse entire files or only on demand?

Tags: php

If I write an entire website in a single App class PHP file and include it in every page, then from each page, I call only the related functions and render the page (separate template files) from the App class.

Does PHP actually read the entire script or does it just try to search for only the functions being called? This is with regards to large apps, load times and bandwidth.

Comment: Writing an entire application in a huge single file/class is a bad idea regardless of its actual performance. Call it a maintainence nightmare.

Comment: please do not, ever, write a total app in only one class/file. It seems easy at one point, but altering stuff later is killing. And how would you divide in your presentation and business logic...?

Comment: Write a syntax error inside a function that never gets called and see if your script runs.

Comment: @MikeB yea.. i was thinking if it worked like that. Similar to ... C/C++ parsing of template classes. I would imagine the parser sort of "inline" everything according to the sequence of the functions appearing. Everything else are ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP reads, compiles, and executes the entire script. This is the only reliable way for it to know where all the functions begin and end.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

"When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward."

Answer (score 0):

If you were to write the **entire** app in a single file and in a single class it would surely be parsed. PHP would otherwise not know the structure of your class. However, once parsed PHP can be set to store the parsed files so a complete **re-parse** does not have to be done next time.

As answer to the second part of your question. PHP parses the **entire** contents of included files. The only distinction is text outside of the  tags which does not have to be tokenized etc.